# Check if a set of groups are present in rest api

Tags: rest, groups

I have a set of Sharepoint groups to be created with RestApi. But before creating i have to check if the group doenst exist already and then create. Is there a way to send multiple group names and find out if they are already present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `/Web/SiteGroups` with multiple `$filter` values, e.g.,

```
_api/Web/SiteGroups?$filter=Title eq 'GroupA' or Title eq 'GroupB'
```

Afterwards you would have to cross-reference results with your own names, e.g., with underscore:

_.difference(yourGroupNames, _.pluck(groups, 'Title'))